# Can I deploy and use my new custom web template at an existing site collection?

Tags: custom, web-template

I am using sharepoint 2010 and VS2010. I have crated a custom web template and when I deploy it I need to create a new site collection where my custom template will be available if I create a new sub site.

But the problem is, there is already a site collection. I would like to use my new created custom web template on this site template, when I create a new subsite.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the site collection first without selecting a template for the root site collection. You will see "select later" (or something similar) on the template selection section when creating new site collection. Then install the template on the site collection, and only then navigate to the new site collection and it will ask you for the template.

You can also create "templateless" site collection using PowerShell.